# Emberjs equivalent to Angular filter ng model search

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ember.js, ember-cli

Is there an easy way to apply a search filter like angular:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="resultFilter" placeholder="Search">

<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="result in results | filter:resultFilter">{{result.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

this filters the result by what ever is typed in the input box making an awsomely simple search feature. Is there a simple Emberjs equivalent or this one of those simple perks of anuglarjs?

Comment: essentially you would add that logic in the controller backing the template.  here's an ugly example showing it: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/yoriceqape/1/edit

Comment: @Kingpin2k I think thats the answer :) not a comment.

Comment: it's totally an answer, but I didn't feel like writing up a non-ugly answer at the time, so comment was the less egregious issue at the time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Ember.computed.filter` to dynamically filter your model.

```
App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
   searchKeyword: '',

   searchResults: Ember.computed.filter('model', function(model) {
       return model.filterProperty('name', this.get('searchKeyword'));
   }).property('model', 'name')
});
```

with example template

```
{{input type="text" valueBinding="searchKeyword"}}

<ul>
{{#each result in searchResults}}
   <li>{{result.name}}</li>
{{/each}}
</ul>
```

Comment: How would I do the same thing in a component?

Comment: The same way as you would do in controller. Both inherit from Ember Object. In Ember 2 you can also use helpers for filtering arrays in templates